# How to load and save Langchain's memory model

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to build a chat service that uses OpenAI as LLM and langchain for remembering the context.

The model I am using is "VectorStoreRetrieverMemory".

`const memory = VectorStoreRetrieverMemory()`

The backend is in Nodejs. Flow goes something like this :

- I make a call when a message is added.
- Right now, I load all the previous messages and add them in `memory` as `memory.save_context({input:inputmsg}, {output:outputMsg})`
- then I make the call to LLM with the previous history.

This makes each call a very long since it has to add all previous messages at every message.

I wish to somehow save the `memory` object and just load that to pass it into the LLM call, updating it when returning a new message, and then saving the model again.

If there is a better way to do this pls do guide me.

I tried to find ways to save the model, but fail to find any.

Answer (score 1):

LangChain comes with various types of memory that you can implement, depending on your application and use case (with links to LangChain's JS documentation):

1. [Conversation Buffer](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/how_to/buffer)
2. [Conversation Buffer Window](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/how_to/buffer_window)
3. [Entity](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/how_to/entity_summary_memory)
4. [Vector store-backed memory](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/how_to/vectorstore_retriever_memory)
5. [Conversation Summary](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/how_to/summary)
6. [Conversation Summary Buffer](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/how_to/summary_buffer)

You're on the right track, though keep in mind that, so far, there is no way to give history context/memory to the LLM other than storing the entire history and passing it to the LLM as context.

Answer (score 0):

Langchain has [Conversation Summary](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/types/summary)

> Now let's take a look at using a slightly more complex type of memory
>
> - ConversationSummaryMemory. This type of memory creates a summary of the conversation over time. This can be useful for condensing
>   information from the conversation over time. Conversation summary
>   memory summarizes the conversation as it happens and stores the
>   current summary in memory. This memory can then be used to inject the
>   summary of the conversation so far into a prompt/chain. This memory is
>   most useful for longer conversations, where keeping the past message
>   history in the prompt verbatim would take up too many tokens.

Be aware that there is a trade-off here. the response will take longer because you make two API calls. one to generate the original response, second to generate the summart